# Should I dispose of my cheap bike or is it worthy to keep?

Tags: road-bike, frugal

I was given a bike that cost £150.  How can I tell if this bike is rubbish or not?

Comment: If you decide not to keep it, at least sell it to someone. Any bike can be put to use by somebody.  Even if it's just for spare parts.

Comment: Space is clearly a question but a backup bike even if rubbish can be useful if you commute. Also you can use it as a learning aid if you want to get better at maintenance.

Comment: Photos and specs would help.  Is it heavy or light?   Does it fit your lifestyle ?

Comment: You keep it if you like riding it,at least sometimes, more than anything else you have.  If not, you sell it if you can find a buyer.  If not, you junk it.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on your definition of rubbish! If I were to guess it is probably all entry level components, unless they have been upgraded. That would be the first indicator. You can cross reference them by typing model numbers into Google.

However, before throwing it away I would recommend putting it up for sale, or even better if there is someone in need, why not dust it off, polish it up and donate it to the less fortunate!

Comment: You might also find charities or co-ops in your local area who will take unwanted bicycles to refit for people who need them.

Answer (score 1):

Now, little details was given on your post so it'd difficult to give accurate answer. Your bike is probably good for short commutes, but not for serious exercising. Also cheap bike usually is less attractive to thieves.

Cheap bikes also usually have weak parts and if you break something you can quickly go beyond economical repair.